# Open in Explorer

Tags: c++, windows, explorer

How do you open a path in explorer by code in c++. I googled and couldn't find any thing but systems commands to do this, however, i dont want it to block or show the console window.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You probably are looking for the [`ShellExecute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) function in `shellapi.h`.  It is called with an "action verb", a path, and optional parameters.  In your case this will want either "open" or "explore" as follows:

```
ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "C:\\", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

This will open an unattached explorer window at C:.  ShellExecute() will give basically the same action as typing in a command at the Run dialog.  It will also handle URLs, so the following will open up the user's default browser:

```
ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "http://www.google.com", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Although make sure to pay attention to the note in the documentation that ShellExecute relies on COM (Although your code doesn't have to worry about any COM objects itself).

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE)
```

Comment: Works a treat and i didnt need to init the com interface thing as well

Comment: error C2664: 'ShellExecuteW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [5]' to 'LPCWSTR'

Comment: The header to include is Shellapi.h.

Comment: Didn't know about "action verbs" at all. Thanks. (There's a back slash missing in the  open example).

Answer (score 2):

This does not show the command window, just opens the directory.

```
system("explorer C:\\");
```

Comment: @berlindev Where does 'system' come from?

Comment: @Harsh kurra You probably need to put your path in quotes. e.g. system("explorer \"C:\\me path with spaces\\". Otherwise explorer will think your path is multiple parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using VS2017, using as follows works:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"YourFolderPath\\YourFile.xxx", NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);
```

also reference [ShellExecute to open an .exe in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558259/shellexecute-to-open-an-exe-in-c)