# ShellExecute to open an .exe in C++

Tags: c++, shellexecute

I am trying to open sigverif.exe from my code in c++ but the return value is 2 and .exe does not open

```
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\sigverif.exe"), NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);
```

If I open the sigverif.exe from run command typing

> "C:\Windows\system32\sigverif.exe"

it works fine

What could be the issue?

Comment: The backslash \ has a special meaning in a string. Either escape it using two \\ or write the string as a verbatim `@"string"`

Comment: The same line of code works for opening other executable in the same location

Comment: use one '\'  instead of  2 '//' . Pay attention to flags

Comment: What's the deal with `SW_RESTORE`? Shouldn't you be using `SW_SHOW`? Pretty sure that's the default mode for opening new windows.

Comment: I tried SW_SHOW as well, it makes no difference

Comment: Consider c:\windows\sysnative so it even works in a 32-bit process.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Does  c:\windows\sysnative works for all OS(XP, windows 7 and Higher version ) and for both 32 bit and 64 bit ?

Comment: Hmm, you'll know what to try next when sysnative doesn't get the job done.  Assuming that the OS is installed to c:\windows is already wrong btw.

Comment: I suspect this may be the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11586139/156811 try using `runas` instead of `open` and see what happens.

Comment: I tried runas aswell

Comment: default open is done with `NULL`, `"open"` might not be defined

Answer (score 4):

> the return value is 2 and .exe does not open

The return value based on [System Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) means **ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**.

Yes, indeed your application failed to find the given path, because you're building it on `x86`, where Windows's *automatic redirection* involves, and replace `C:\Windows\System32` with `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, which contains 32-bit binaries for Windows.

You have two options:

Either you just build it on `x64`, or [disable the automatic redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743.aspx) by using `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` as follows:

```
PVOID OldValue = nullptr;
Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&OldValue);
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\sigverif.exe"), NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);
```

Be aware that `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` affects globally in the current thread, as you can find more detail in the page:

> **Note** The `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` function affects all file operations performed by the current thread, which can have unintended consequences if file system redirection is disabled for any length of time....

So make sure it won't affect other operations unintentionally, or set it back to `enabled` immediately after your desire is resolved by invoking [Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365744.aspx).