# Is there a universal way to open a location in the default file explorer in C?

Tags: c, linux, windows

I am writing a C program that needs to open a location in the default file explorer (e.g. open `C:\Program Files (x86)\somefolder` in the Windows file explorer, or open `/usr/share/somefolder` in [Nautilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files)/[Nemo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemo_(file_manager))/whatever default file explorer program is set).

Is there an universal way to do that, as in a way that uses the same code for both Windows and Linux?

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354902/open-in-explorer) that uses `ShellExecute()`, but this probably doesn't work on Linux.
So, is it possible, and if not, is there a way to separate the code for Linux and Windows?

Comment: I believe the best way is to use the preprocessor: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6649992/6874310).

Comment: @JardelLucca I see, so is there no code that works on both OS?

Comment: I don't it's possible. You could maybe use a cross-platform solution for this, such as converting your code to python. I'd rather go with the preprocessor way, because it seems the way it works now you have to compile the code for Linux and separately for Windows anyway.

Comment: @JardelLucca Python would have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, thanks! I thought there was a package for this. What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12407305/6874310)? Seems to work. (Using a module named webbrowser to open the file explorer seems quite a hack though!)

Comment: @JardelLucca Ah, I didn't know about that one. Although at least on Linux, this will open the directory in the webbrowser, not in the native file explorer (like you would get with `system("open /usr/share/somefolder")`).

Comment: @G.Sliepen Funny it actually opened on Nautilus for me. At any rate it seems it's not really cross-platform anyway...

Comment: The utility `open` is a very handy, but only on MacOSX. The equivalent Windows utility is `start`. (In fact, `start` pre-dates `open`, 1995?)

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in pure C. In fact, the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf) does not mention "Linux" or "Windows" at all. Even the words "operating system" only occur twice. The first occurrence is in 5.1.2.1-1:

> In a freestanding environment (in which C program execution may take place without any benefit of an operating system) [...]

The alternative to a freestanding environment is a *hosted environment* (5.1.2-1). The standard continues to use the term "hosted environment", but does not distinguish between different operating systems.

A common solution is to use preprocessor macros to conditionally compile code depending on the target operating system. E.g.:

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    // Open in Linux. E.g. // system("xdg-open ...");
#elif __CYGWIN__
    // Open in Windows.
#else
#error "Error: OS not supported."
#endif
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive) contains a list of operating systems and corresponding macros.